# How to convert a message to an integer to encrypt it with RSA?

Tags: math, cryptography, rsa

In encryption methods like RSA, we operate on an integer which represents our message. I've toyed around with converting the string to an array of bytes and working one character at a time, but that seems overly slow and the RSA algorithm is designed to work with the entire message.

How do we convert a string to a representation (integer, big integer etc) in which we can apply our cryptographic algorithm too?

Answer (score 6):

In typical usage, you don't actually encrypt the entire message using RSA.  Instead, you encrypt the encryption key for a symmetric block cipher (like AES) using RSA, then encrypt your stream of data using that block cipher.

**Do not attempt to do this on your own!**  You have to be very careful with how you do the conversion, including setting up a secure padding scheme and using the block cipher correctly and in a secure mode.  You might want to look using language-provided crypto libraries or a standard library like OpenSSL.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this isn't a production implementation, more of an educational implementation.

If I understand correctly, you're saying that we generate a key and encrypt it using RSA, then use that key for implementing AES?

Comment: @DamonSwayn- Yes, that's right.  Just be careful when using AES to set it up properly (use either CBC or CTR mode for security, choose a cryptographically random IV, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Think about how integers and strings are represented in memory. A 32-bit integer takes up four 8-bit bytes, and a 64-bit integer takes up eight bytes. A string is stored as bytes too, and in case of ASCII, each characters is represented by one byte. (UTF-8 and UTF-16 are variable length encodings, but it's still bytes.)

There is nothing to convert, because all datatypes are represented by bytes internally.

There's no reason this can't be extended to, say, 2048-bit integers for use with RSA.